# Quintic equation with integer coefficients

Tags: special-functions, irreducible-polynomials, quintics

I am looking for a way to find a closed form of the real root of the quintic eq. with integer coefficients:
$x^5+3x^4+4x^3+x-1=0$.

According to the numerical calculation the root $x_0\approx 0.4591337233102075...$. I am interested in representing the root via a function to use it in further calculation. Probably there is not any closed form, but what about other ways to get a function which produces the constant? Any suggestions?

Just to be more clear the root appears in the problem I posted a few years ago: [Bath towel on the rope: minimize the area of self-intersection of a folded rectangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23746/bath-towel-on-the-rope-minimize-the-area-of-self-intersection-of-a-folded-recta)
Thank you for any help.

Comment: The Galois group of the polynomial is $S_5$ and in particular not solvable, so there is no closed form for any root in terms of radicals. For an exact representation there are various choices; see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical

Comment: Even the formulas for degree $3$ and $4$ are too complicated , so usually not used. Degree $5$ and more is in general not solvable by radicals , and all approaches for "exact closed forms" in fact need after all numerical methods , so it is not wirth the effort and you can apply the numerical method directly.

Comment: Any series representation? I'd like to add 'Bath rowel on the rope' problem to OEIS which usually has formula to calculate.

Comment: “Representing the root via a function to use it in further calculation”. FWIW, a general quintic equation can be solved using the Jacobi theta function.

Comment: @KStarGamer Yes. And for added info, the Jacobi theta function can also be expressed as quotients of the Dedekind eta function.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII Yes indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We'll give a closed-form to your quintic root. As Klein showed in his "*Lectures on the Icosahedron*", there is indeed such a thing though it goes *beyond radicals*.

**Two** special functions may be used: the *Dedekind eta function* $\eta(\tau)$ and the *hypergeometric function* $_2F_1$. The *Bring quintic form* will be avoided since that involves $2$nd-deg and $4$th-deg transformations, and to undo those will result in a mess.

Fortunately, there are other solutions. And the nice thing about the Klein-Brioschi result is one just uses nested *square roots* (unlike the Bring form which needs cube roots).

---

**I. Principal quintic**

First reduce the quintic to principal form, and yours is special in that its Tschirnhausen transformation needs only rational coefficients. Given,

$$x^5+3x^4+4x^3+x-1=0$$

Let $(x+1)^2-y=0$. Eliminating $x$ between the two using [resultants in WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Resultant%5Bx%5E5%2B3x%5E4%2B4x%5E3%2Bx-1%2C%20-%28x%2B1%29%5E2%2By%2C%20x%5D) yields the principal quintic form,

$$y^5 - 8y^2 + 4y - 16=0$$

which has discriminant $d = 2^{23}\times47.$ The prime $47$ will appear in the second method.

---

**II. First Method**

We'll use [Tyma Gaidash's method](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4728991/4781) which is simpler than Klein's. Given,

$$y^5 - 8y^2 + 4y - 16=0$$

or equivalently,

$$\left(\tfrac{y}{2}\right)^5-\left(\tfrac{y}{2}-\tfrac{1+\sqrt{-31}}8\right)\left(\tfrac{y}{2}-\tfrac{1-\sqrt{-31}}8\right)=0$$

then the five roots are,

$$y_k=-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^\frac{(2k+1)\pi i n}5 \frac{(q)^\frac n5}{(p)^{\frac{4n}5-1}} \frac{\left(\frac n5\right)!}{n!\,\Gamma\big(2-\frac{4n}5\big)}\;{_2 F_1}\left(1-n,-\frac n5;2-\frac{4n}5;\frac pq\right)\qquad$$

for $k = 0,1,2,3,4,$ and where $p, q = \frac{1\pm\sqrt{-31}}8,$ with *gamma function* $\Gamma(n).$  Reversing the Tshirnhausen transformation, then the real root is,

$$x_2 = -1+\sqrt{y_2} \; \approx \; 0.45913372331$$

though one has to choose the correct sign of the square root.

---

**III. Second Method**

We can also use the [Klein-Brioschi method](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4725226/4781). The real root is,

$$\quad x_2 = -1+\sqrt{\frac{pm+q}{rm^2-3}}\approx 0.45913372331$$

where,

$$m=-\frac{u^2-5}{w^3}\sqrt{\frac{u^2+2u+5}{-r\;}}$$
$$u =\frac{\eta(\tau/5)}{\eta(5\tau)},\quad w =\frac{\eta(\tau)}{\eta(5\tau)}$$
$$\tau = 2+\frac{_2F_1\big(\frac16,\frac56,1,1-\alpha\big)}{_2F_1\big(\frac16,\frac56,1,\alpha\big)}\sqrt{-1}$$
$$\alpha = \tfrac12\left(1-\sqrt{\frac{r}{r-1728}}\right)$$
and $(p,q,r)$ are the constants,
\begin{align}
\qquad p &= \frac{128\;}{259^3} (34323438 + 645563 \sqrt{470})\\[4pt] 
q &= \frac{4}{259} (431 + 32 \sqrt{470})\\[4pt] 
r &= \frac{320 (583125 + 30692 \sqrt{470})^3}{259^5 (2263 + 156 \sqrt{470})}+1728\\ \end{align}
where the formulas ($p = e,\, q = \lambda,\, r= 1/f$) in this [Klein-Brioschi post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4725226/4781).

**P.S.** In short, just choose which of the two methods you prefer.

Comment: Thank you. so much. If possible, could you clarify in your answer how you find the constants for the III Second Method being specific to the quintic eq?

Comment: @MikhailGaichenkov I've edited the answer so the formula link to the constants ($p,q,r$) will be closer.

Comment: @ Tito Piezas III I've proposed the sequence for OEIS https://oeis.org/draft/A366185

Comment: @MikhailGaichenkov You mean the real root $x \approx 0.4591$? Ok, the roots do have neat series expansion via Tyma’s method.

Comment: Yes, indeed, the real root to be added in allocated A366185. I hope you can see it. If you can add in it the comments in OEIS about Tyma's method, please.

Comment: @MikhailGaichenkov I forgot how to log in to OEIS. Anyway, I see from the draft you provided a link to this MSE post. That should suffice for the interested reader.

Answer (score 0):

I take it as a perfect example for a method using continued fraction see for that [Got a factored version of the Taylor's series?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4738155/got-a-factored-version-of-the-taylors-series)

1.You need to transform the coefficients

2.Apply the iteration

3.You have a rational approximation of the root (always useful)

On the other hand see the good answer due to TitoPiezasIII to compare .